# Deploying Storybook components in an npm package

Tags: vue.js, npm, deployment, vuejs3, storybook

I'm currently setting up the design system for my company. We currently have 4 applications running in parallel and we'd like to have a single design system for all the applications.

So we've created a storybook in which we've created a few components in VueJS, but we already have a problem. I can't figure out whether or not it's possible to create an npm package containing just our components, their associated management files and the tailwind configuration.

That's why I'm asking you, is it possible?

If not, I understand that many people create a separate package and import it into the Storybook. Is this better?

I tried deploying only the components but it didn't work. I didn't want to waste any more time and I looked for good practices on the subject but I couldn't find anything conclusive...